# How to skip unzipping a file that already exists?

Tags: batch-file, unzip, exists

```
ECHO Unzipping "%build1%"...
unzip -o "%build1%" -d "%exbuild1%" >NUL

ECHO Done.
ECHO.

ECHO Unzipping "%build2%"...
unzip -o "%build2%" -d "%exbuild2%" >NUL

ECHO Done.
ECHO.
```

How to skip unzipping a file that already exists? If the unzipped file is not esists, unzip it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if not exist "%exbuild1%\%build1%" (
  ECHO Unzipping "%build1%"...
  unzip -o "%build1%" -d "%exbuild1%" >NUL

  ECHO Done.
  ECHO.
) else (
  ECHO Build already exists
)
```

?

See more about [IF](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) command.

Comment: It's not what I want. I have in the folder a file with zip and unziped extensions. I want that if the script will see that in the folder I have already the unzipped file it will not do the unzipping.

Comment: @GorArakelyan - you haven't pointed the file name in your question.... You can add the file name in the path of the `IF`  check. Or a few files. Though this is the way to check file or directory existence with batch.